# To think...I think

Tags: phrase-request, idioms, phrases, idiom-request

I am wondering if this is the correct usage

> To think I thought I had seen everything when she slipped on her own
>   spit, **I think** I cannot be surprised anymore.

I am wondering if this is the only phrase that starts with "To think", I am not sure if this is the most widely used set phrases, I am wondering what are other forms other than the one that ends with "I think". Could you tell me if there are other set phrases/construction that starts with "To think"?

Comment: What do you mean by "other constructions"? Do you consider *to think is to be* a different construction?

Comment: The example should be punctuated as two sentences.

Answer (score 1):

Often, sentences can start with "(and) to think", usually used to underscore or emphasize the following statement or observation. Aside from that, "to think" can start sentences,  in particular when functioning as the infinitive form of the verb. As an example, "To think is to stretch the brain", an expression that I just made up (but I'm sure there are a bunch that are in common use). *To think* of a sentence starting like that, all it takes is a bit of imagination and an understanding of verbs!